# What command puts a line break between the information being outputted?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Using the Terminal on Mac, I need to find and display only the MAC addresses *with a line break following each address*.

```
ifconfig | grep 'ether ' | cut -b 7-24
```

returns

```
38:c9:86:3c:ed:16
28:f0:76:3c:c2:e4
1a:00:01:87:0d:30
1a:00:01:87:0d:31
3a:c9:86:c3:c8:00
0a:f0:76:3c:c2:e4
5e:05:5b:91:c5:99
```

What command can I use that will put a line break after each address?

Comment: ?? What do you mean, the output you show looks to have line-breaks. OR is each line really 2 addresses? (duh on my part) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter you were correct, the output does have line breaks. I meant I needed to add an additional newline after each address - but I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would use sed to replace a character, but I've never been able to find a way for sed to insert newline characters.

To get the output you want, you would have to insert 2 newlines at the end of each line:

> for i in $(ifconfig  |grep 'ether' |awk '{print $2}'); do printf
>   "$i\n\n"; done

Output:

> 38:c9:86:3c:ed:16
>
> 28:f0:76:3c:c2:e4
>
> 1a:00:01:87:0d:30
>
> 1a:00:01:87:0d:31
>
> 3a:c9:86:c3:c8:00
>
> 0a:f0:76:3c:c2:e4
>
> 5e:05:5b:91:c5:99